# Chrome OS Version 94.0.4606.124 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, bash

```
[Error/main.rs:181] ERROR: unknown command: shell
```

I've been having this problem for a couple of days. I am in developer by turning off my `chrome:power-esc-refresh` and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and you know the rest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Chrome is now Version 96+ Have you tried updating? Have you tried reinstalling Chrome? Uninstall Chrome, restart, install the new version and test.

Comment: “and you know the rest” - We actually don’t know the rest